# Error does not indicate an object instance

Tags: c#, winforms

I use it DevExpress

I'm trying to add a new group, and add it to ComboBoxEdit, but the error shows that it does not indicate an object instance.
I pass the parameter in different forms... How can I do?

1 form InformationOfStudents:

```
    public void LoadingIDGroupTeacher(string indexTeacher)
    {

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "GETGroupsTeacher";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        sqlParameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@index",
            Value = int.Parse(indexTeacher)
        };
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            //an error appears here

ComboBoxGroups.Properties.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()); 
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

2 form when I want to add a new group:

```
    private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        new InformaitionOfStudents().LoadingIDGroupTeacher(usIndex);
        Dispose();

    }
```

T-SQL procedures:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETGroupsTeacher]
 @index int
 AS
 SELECT NameGroup FROM dbo.Groups WHERE Teacher = @index
```

Comment: Please [edit] and give the complete actual error message

Comment: Calling `Dispose()` on what I'm assuming is a form in a WinForms button click handler is likely not going to end well.  You are Disposing of something that is in the midst of having called your handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
     if(!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(0))
          ComboBoxGroups.Properties.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Or:

```
     ComboBoxGroups.Properties.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0)?.ToString() ?? "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ComboBoxGroups` is a DevExpress `DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ComboBoxEdit` control you should probably use:

```
ComboBoxGroups.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

and not:

```
ComboBoxGroups.Properties.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

And the `Dispose();` in the button event handler in "2 form" will Dispose the dialog "2 form" so that's probably not a good idea.